# Golang DynamoDB UnmarshalListOfMaps Returns Array of Empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table of products (id (int), active (bool), name (string), price (int)) and when I retrieve and attempt to unmarshal the list, it returns empty.

```
[{},{}]
```

Struct:

```
type Product struct {
id     int
active bool
name   string
price  int }
```

And the code to unmarshal is here:

```
    params := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
    TableName: aws.String("Products"),
}
result, err := service.Scan(params)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Errorf("failed to make Query API call, %v", err)
}

var products = []Product{}

var error = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(result.Items, &products)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only public fields can be unmarshaled.

Make your struct fields public using uppercase letter and use `json` attribute to map them to data values:

```
type Product struct {
    ID     int    `json:"id"`
    Active bool   `json:"active"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Price  int    `json:"price"`
}
```

Update Oct 2021:

AWS SDK v1 uses `json` attribute for DynamoDB serialization.
new version [aws-sdk-go-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2) contains breaking change and moved from `json` to `dynamodbav` attribute to separate JSON and DynamoDB names.

For V2 struct should look like this:

```
type Product struct {
    ID     int    `dynamodbav:"id"`
    Active bool   `dynamodbav:"active"`
    Name   string `dynamodbav:"name"`
    Price  int    `dynamodbav:"price"`
}
```

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#Marshal

Comment: OP should probably use `dynamodbav` instead of `json`, e.g: `dynamodbav:"id"`since they are working with dynamodb.

Comment: You saved my life